# How to convert ContentVersion VersionData to String

Tags: apex, contentversion

How would I convert CSV data stored in the `VersionData` field of object `ContentVersion` into a CSV String.

According to the documentation:

- [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ContentVersion.htm)

The field `VersionData` is of type `base64`

So how to I convert that into a human readable string:

```
String contents = (?) contentVersions[0].VersionData;
```

Using `EncodingUtil.Base64Encode`

```
String contents = EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(contentVersions[0].VersionData);
```

Does **not** return the CSV data, it returns this data:

> T1BQT1JUVU5JVFlJRCxQ...

When I am expecting:

> field1__c, field2__c, field3__c...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Robs, You can convert the blob value of ContentVersion to string as below:-

```
ContentVersion cv=[select id,ContentDocumentId,versiondata from Contentversion where ContentDocumentId='0697E000000HW12' ];
    Blob csvFileBody =cv.VersionData;
    String csvAsString= csvFileBody.toString();
    List<String> csvFileLines= csvAsString.split('\n');
    system.debug(csvFileLines);
```

toString() will give the String value and and split('\n') will split those value.

You can further split as running a for loop on List you got from above code:-

```
 set<String> columnvalue = new set<string>();
for(Integer i=1; i<csvFileLines.size(); i++){
   string[] csvRecordData1 = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
   columnvalue.add(csvRecordData1[0]); // here 0 indicates the no. of column from which value you want to store 
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The documentation says `VersionData` is base64: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ContentVersion.htm but yes `.toString` works, thanks

Comment: Blob is a collection of binary data stored as a single object. Base64 is a group of similar binary-to-text encoding schemes that represent binary data in an ASCII string format by translating it into a radix-64 representation. That is why you are getting the versiondata value as T1BQT1JUVU5JVFlJRCxQ...

Answer (score 3):

VersionData is a blob, You want to convert blob into actual data and not encoded base64 String data.

The way you can do it is just call the **toString** method on blob.

So code to convert blob to actual data is

```
String myString = 'StringToBlob';
Blob myBlob = Blob.valueof(myString); //Assume my blob is your versionData
System.assertEquals('StringToBlob', myBlob.toString()); //Magic happens here.
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_blob.htm#apex_System_Blob_toString

Answer (score 1):

Using EncodingUtil. Please check this code

```
 EncodingUtil.base64Encode(contentVersions[0].VersionData);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question. Any thoughts?